# Javascript sort dates in array by year DESC, then month ASC, then day ASC

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, sorting, date

I have an array of classes and the dates they were offered coming back from an AJAX to PHP call.  It's returned as 'data' so we'll just call our array data:

```
var data = [{
  "course": "First Aid",
  "courseDate": "2016-04-25T00:00:00-06:00"
}, {
  "course": "CPR",
  "courseDate": "2016-04-06T00:00:00-06:00"
}, {
  "course": "ASL1",
  "courseDate": "2016-01-07T00:00:00-06:00"
}, {
  "course": "ASL2",
  "courseDate": "2016-03-25T00:00:00-06:00"
},
...etc...
];
```

I need to be able to display them sorted by date descending.  I'm using this simple function:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
   a = new Date(a.courseDate);
   b = new Date(b.courseDate);
   return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
});

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
   $('#courseHist').append('<br />' + val.course+' - '+val.courseDate);
});
```

As expected, I'm getting a return of

```
1st Aid - 2016-04-25...
CPR - 2016-04-06...
ASL2 - 2016-03-25...
ASL1 - 2015-12-07...
```

Which is, technically, sorted by date descending.  However, I need the return to sort by year descending, then month ascending, then date ascending.  Like this:

```
ASL2 - 2016-03-25...
CPR - 2016-04-06...
1st Aid - 2016-04-25...
ASL1 - 2015-12-07...
```

I know I need to break my date return up into chunks and arrange from there but I just can't wrap my head around how to do that.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Alternately, I could do it on the PHP side if anyone has a solution for that.

I have a fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/dkaufmanjs/kdLg5k8a/) if you want to mess with it.  - updated with working code from user blex

Comment: Once you've made Date instances, you can use [the Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to extract the year (`.getFullYear()`), month (`.getMonth()`), day of month (`.getDate()`), etc.

Comment: That was my initial thought but I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to actually write it out in a function.  That does what I need it to do, that is.

Comment: Fixed Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ts5mks95/ It's going to start by sorting by year (descending), then if they are equal, sort by month (ascending), then if they are equal, sort them by day of the month (ascending).

Comment: @DanKaufman compare the years first. If they're equal, compare the months. If they're equal, compare the days.

Comment: Man- I swear the longer I do this job the more I overlook the easy stuff.  Thanks, blex- that nailed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can split the data and sort it independently by year desc,  month asc and day asc.

```js
var data = [{ "course": "First Aid", "courseDate": "2016-04-25T00:00:00-06:00" }, { "course": "CPR", "courseDate": "2016-04-06T00:00:00-06:00" }, { "course": "ASL1", "courseDate": "2016-01-07T00:00:00-06:00" }, { "course": "ASL2", "courseDate": "2016-03-25T00:00:00-06:00" }, { "course": "ASL2X", "courseDate": "2015-03-25T00:00:00-06:00" }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aa = a.courseDate.split(/\D/),
        bb = b.courseDate.split(/\D/);
    return bb[0] - aa[0] || aa[1] - bb[1] || aa[2] - bb[2];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Even cleaner!  Nice.  Thanks.

Comment: You can do `split(/\D/)`, there is no need for the *g* flag. Saved 3 characters! ;-)

Comment: @RobG, ... there is always a shorter regex ... :)